# Linking a 3rd table

Tags: sql

I have the following ERD:

[image]

At a high-level, how would we go about listing all **product_sku** for a customer with an email of, lets say, **john.smith@gmail.com** AND an 'a**ctive**' subscription?

What I've tried is joining 1 of the tables, but if I use a join to join again a second time, wouldn't I lose my data from the 1st->2nd join? I read up on joins and was not able to understand so was hoping to get a better explanation from a pro.

I don't see any relationship between the product and customer entities, which is why I'm confused. I know there's a relationship between customer and subscription, but then how do we go that step further to link to product? Ugh.

Thanks,
Zain

Comment: The terms you should Google are "SQL Joins"

Comment: @dfundako Hi, I've already done that and know how to use the various joins; however, how do you join 2 tables that don't have a common variable? customer and subscription can be joined on fk_customer, but how do you join customer with product?

Comment: A customer has a subscription. A subscription is made up of products. Hence, you should be able to find out what subscriptions a customer has, and since you know what products are aligned with each subsciption, you should know what products a customer gets. Thats how joins work.

Comment: @dfundako So yes a subscription is made up of products, but what variable would I be using in this case to join the product and subscription tables? I may be misunderstanding which table a FK is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I believe:

```
SELECT t1.product_sku
FROM product t1
INNER JOIN order t2 ON t1.id_product = t2.fk_product
INNER JOIN subscription t3 ON t2.fk_subscription = t3.id_subscription
INNER JOIN customer t4 ON t3.fk_customer = t4.id_customer
WHERE customer.email = 'fresh_frank@gmail.com'
AND subscription.status = 'active'
```

Thanks